# Migration Jave 11 _ How to resolve : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException

Tags: jaxb, maven-3, maven-jaxb2-plugin, java-11

I'm migrating my java project from **8** to **11** version.

As **javax.activation** has been removed from JDK 11, so I added it to Maven pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
  <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The dependency is listed in "Externat librairies" but every time I run "mvn clean install" to build my project, I get this error :

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
... 51 more
```

Have you any idea please ?
Thanks

Comment: Java 11 is not supported yet. Please file an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly @lexicore is no more here to answer but the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools) (which was renamed `jaxb-tools` since get merged with other related jaxb-projects) is still (and back) under active development and is now supporting jdk11 as well as jdk17 and even jdk21.

Support of jaxb-jakarta is also OK (jaxb3 and jaxb4)

You can check the [migration guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Tools-Migration-Guide) to get the latest versions available based on targeted jaxb version.